# Set window size in graphics.h on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, bgi

`initwindow()` doesn't seem to work, nor does `initgraph()`.

How do I set the width and height of the window?

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? A quick google search showed up this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu

Comment: Use the X libraries, or OpenGL.

Comment: It is unusual to see someone asking how to get a 40 year-old DOS library working in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I got my info from https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu...

```
/*  demo.c*/
#include<graphics.h> 
int main()
{
   int gd = DETECT,gm,left=100,top=100,right=200,bottom=200,x= 300,y=150,radius=50;
   initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);
   rectangle(left, top, right, bottom);
   circle(x, y, radius);
   bar(left + 300, top, right + 300, bottom);
   line(left - 10, top + 150, left + 410, top + 150);
   ellipse(x, y + 200, 0, 360, 100, 50);
   outtextxy(left + 100, top + 325, "C Graphics Program");

   delay(5000);
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

This seems like `graphics.h` has a defined `DETECT` variable that I would assume would detect your default width / height. Look into that and I think you may find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't do this.

This library is ancient. I wouldn't be surprised if you found a system that doesn't support it.
**Use any of:**

- [X](http://xfce.org)
- [libSDL](http://libsdl.org/)
- [GTK+](http://gtk.org)
- [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/)

<sub>*(Okay, you [can do this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/materials/cppdoc/graphics.html#Function:initGraphics), but please don't)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The BGI library is very old. But it was very good, convenient, and useful. Consequently, there are quite a few working versions floating around.

Some versions let you set any arbitrary window size.
Some versions only permit some window sizes.
Some versions don't let you choose.

Hence, you absolutely *must* read the documentation that came with whatever version you are using to see how to properly initialize the window, and which function to call.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
initwindow(1000, 1000); /* (size X, size Y) */
setactivepage(0);
```

Comment: No. Try not. Do. Or do not. There is no try.